# Getting anonyous type error in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I have following query (just an example),

```
List<int> batchId = entity.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct().ToList();
List<int> optionId = entity.Select(x => x.OptionId).Distinct().ToList();
List<int> prodId = entity.Select(x => x.ProductOption.ProductId).Distinct().ToList();
var itemsCount = (from source in entity
                  from option in optionId
                  from prod in prodId
                  where source.ProductOption.ProductId == prod
                  where source.Id == id
                  where source.OptionId == option
                  select new { 
                      a = source.abc.Id,
                      b = source.Option.Name,
                      d = prod
                   });
```

I am getting anonymous type error each and every time:

```
<MethodName>b__38(<>f__AnonymousTypef`2 <>
```

What should I do ??

Comment: *Where* are you getting the error, and *what* exactly is the error? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Haseeb Akhtar: Can you please update the LINQ query since it can't visualize parameters like 'id','source.abc.Id' etc? Also can you give complete stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll get this in your entity framework query (one of the three first lines). Therefore I would suggest to check your entity model to find out what's wrong with it.

My guess:

```
   ist<int> prodId = entity.Select(x => x.ProductOption.ProductId).Distinct().ToList();
```

Maybe it's something wrong with the "Entity -> ProductOption" Relation